# Changing HTML Background Image Using JavaScript, depending on time of day (Using Multiple Images)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, background-image

So I'm trying to change the background image of my website to correlate with the time of day.

Ex. It's evening, so background picture would change to a sunset. It's morning, background picture would be a sunrise.

BUT, I am wanting to have the function choose from several arrays of pictures randomly. Such as, I would have an array of 3 evening, an array 3 morning, an array of 3 afternoon, etc. Depending on the time of day, the function would choose a picture randomly from the correlating array and would then use that picture for the background.

I don't know if it's possible, but I would appreciate any guidance.

EDIT:

```
//Greeting based on time of day

var today = new Date();
var hourNow = today.getHours();
var greeting;
var style;

if(hourNow >= 18) {
    greeting = 'Good evening.';
} else if (hourNow >= 12) {
    greeting = 'Good afternoon.';
} else if (hourNow > 0) {
    greeting = 'Good morning.';
} else {
    greeting = 'Hello.';
}


document.write('<h1>' + greeting + '</h1>');
```

There isn't any of the image arrays on there because I really just don't know how to type out an array of the images or even the document.get?.

Comment: Please post your code, let us see what you wrote so far.

Comment: Thanks for providing the code. My answer is here below :)

Comment: @Bryana : Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting your code.

Take a look at this, it's an extension of your code that shows you how to solve the problem. Of course, it's only intended to give you a head start. It surely isn't "production code", but it works :)

Here's the functioning code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
//Greeting based on time of day

var today = new Date();
var hourNow = today.getHours();
var greeting;
var style;

var timeOfDay;            

if(hourNow >= 18) {
    timeOfDay = 1;
} else if (hourNow >= 12) {
    timeOfDay = 2;
} else if (hourNow > 0) {
    timeOfDay = 3;
} else {
    timeOfDay = 0;
}

// Randomize 3 images            
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1) + 1); // Returns a random number between 1 (inclusive) and 4 (exclusive)

switch (timeOfDay) {
    case 1: // Evening
        greeting = 'Good evening.';

        switch (rnd) {
            case 1: document.write('<img src="EveningImage1.jpg" />'); break;
            case 2: document.write('<img src="EveningImage2.jpg" />'); break;
            case 3: document.write('<img src="EveningImage1.jpg" />'); break;
        } 
        break;
    case 2: // Afternoon
        greeting = 'Good afternoon.';

        switch (rnd) {
            case 1: document.write('<img src="AfternoonImage1.jpg" />'); break;
            case 2: document.write('<img src="AfternoonImage2.jpg" />'); break;
            case 3: document.write('<img src="AfternoonImage1.jpg" />'); break;
        } 
        break;
    case 0: // Morning
        greeting = 'Good morning.';

        switch (rnd) {
            case 1: document.write('<img src="MorningImage1.jpg" />'); break;
            case 2: document.write('<img src="MorningImage2.jpg" />'); break;
            case 3: document.write('<img src="MorningImage1.jpg" />'); break;
        } 
        break;
    default: // Generic
        greeting = 'Hello.';

        switch (rnd) {
            case 1: document.write('<img src="GenericImage1.jpg" />'); break;
            case 2: document.write('<img src="GenericImage2.jpg" />'); break;
            case 3: document.write('<img src="GenericImage1.jpg" />'); break;
        }
        break;
} 

document.write('<h1>' + greeting + '</h1>');

        </script>
        <body>

        </body>
    </html>
```

I hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need. `Date()` will return the time and `randOrd()` will randomize the class selection. Refresh the page to see the effect.( or Click "Run the code snippet over and over again to see the effect") Hope this helps :)

```js
function randOrd() {
  return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.3);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  var hourNow = today.getHours();
  var script = document.getElementById('date');
  
  if (hourNow < 12) {
  
    var days = ['day1', 'day2', 'day3'];
    days.sort(randOrd);
    $('#wrapper').each(function(i, val) {
      $(this).addClass(days[i]);
      script.outerHTML += '<h2>Morning</h2>' + Date();
    });
    
  } 
  
  else if (hourNow >= 12 && hourNow <= 17) {
  
    var noon = ['noon1', 'noon2', 'noon3'];
    noon.sort(randOrd);
    $('#wrapper').each(function(i, val) {
      $(this).addClass(noon[i]);
      script.outerHTML += '<h2>Afternoon</h2>' + Date();
    });
    
  } 
  
  else if (hourNow > 17 && hourNow <= 24) {
  
    var evening = ['evening1', 'evening2', 'evening3'];
    evening.sort(randOrd);
    $('#wrapper').each(function(i, val) {
      $(this).addClass(evening[i]);
      script.outerHTML += '<h2>Evening</h2>' + Date();
    });
    
  } 
  
  else /* the hour is not between 0 and 24, so something is wrong */ {
    alert("I'm not sure what time it is!");
  }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#date {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.day1 {
  background: url(http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/30000/nahled/sunny-day.jpg) top center repeat-x #e0d0b7;
}

.day2 {
  background: url(http://ptb-uploads-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/0d246de.jpg) top center repeat-x #e0d0b7;
}

.day3 {
  background: url(http://www.goodlightscraps.com/content/good-morning/good-morning-93.jpg) top center repeat-x #e0d0b7;
}

.evening1 {
  background: url(http://www.imgion.com/images/02/Good-evening-flying-bird.gif) top center repeat-x #887f70;
}

.evening2 {
  background: url(http://www.alltechguide.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/good-evening-sms-in-hindi.jpg) top center repeat-x #887f70;
}

.evening3 {
  background: url(http://www.db18.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Loving-Good-Evening.jpg) top center repeat-x #887f70;
}

.noon1 {
  background: url(http://www.dilsecomments.com/graphics/Good-Afternoon-5677.jpg) top center repeat-x #887f70;
}

.noon2 {
  background: url(http://www.imgion.com/images/02/Sunflowers-good-afternoon.jpg) top center repeat-x #887f70;
}

.noon3 {
  background: url(http://www.dilsecomments.com/graphics/Good-Afternoon-5683.gif) top center repeat-x #887f70;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
  <div id="date"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Jinukurian7/py4ngu7f/3/)**